# Finding when mean equals variance for Weibull distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-function, variance, means

For the 2-parameter Weibull distribution,

The mean $E(X)$ is given as $E(X) = \lambda \Gamma(1+\frac{1}{k})$

The variance is given as $var(X) = \lambda^2 [\Gamma(1+\frac{2}{k})-(\Gamma(1+\frac{2}{k}))^2]$

where $k,\lambda>0$ are the shape and scale parameters respectively.

Solving for $k$, I would like to find analytically when the mean equals the variance for this distribution. But I don't have much experience working with Gamma functions. The only solution I have found so far is $k = \lambda = 1$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You want the combinations of $k$ and $\lambda$ for which the Weibull mean and variance are equal:

$$\lambda  \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\lambda ^2 \left(\Gamma \left(1+\frac{2}{k}\right)-\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^2\right)$$

Just solve for $\lambda$ in terms of $k$:

$$\lambda=\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{2}{k}\right)-\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Apologies. What I want is your equation, but now solving for $k$!

Comment: You can just set $k$ to whatever you want and the get the corresponding value of $\lambda$.

Comment: Gotcha! Though I am wondering if there a clean formula for the reverse where I am setting $\lambda$ to be whatever and getting out the corresponding $k$

Comment: I would bet that there's no clean or even horrendously complicated formula.  However, you might be able to find a good approximation .